# "Could not add subscription" error when WSO2 API Manager starts

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a WSO2 API Manager 2.5.0 installation, deployed in two nodes as active-active. It also has WSO2 Analytics and WSO2 Identity Server as Key Manager.

When each node starts, it leaves three times the same error in logs:

```
2018-11-14 07:56:50,989 [-] [DisruptorInboundEventThread-8] ERROR AndesSubscriptionManager Could not add subscription: subscriptionId=3091b9ba-867b-4539-bf25-fee511d1813d,storageQueue=AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101,protocolType=AMQP,isActive=true,subscriberConnection=Y29ubmVjdGVkSVA9LzEwLjAuMC40OjMzMTgyLzEsY29ubmVjdGVkTm9kZT1OT0RFOk9wZW5EYXRhQXBpTTEvMTAuMC4wLjQscHJvdG9jb2xDaGFubmVsSUQ9Y2Y3NDI4MDgtZGY3MS00NzJhLWFiMTEtOTY1Nzc2ZTBkNTZl
org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.SubscriptionException: StorageQueue: AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101 is not registered while creating subscription id=3091b9ba-867b-4539-bf25-fee511d1813d
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscription.<init>(AndesSubscription.java:136)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscriptionManager.reloadSubscriptionsFromStorage(AndesSubscriptionManager.java:921)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.reloadSubscriptions(InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.java:208)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.updateState(InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.java:76)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundEventContainer.updateState(InboundEventContainer.java:268)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:70)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:40)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-11-14 07:56:50,991 [-] [DisruptorInboundEventThread-8] ERROR AndesSubscriptionManager Could not add subscription: subscriptionId=c9a279eb-6c1f-447c-84bc-c077d33a06e1,storageQueue=AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101,protocolType=AMQP,isActive=true,subscriberConnection=Y29ubmVjdGVkSVA9LzEwLjAuMC40OjM0NTA0LzEsY29ubmVjdGVkTm9kZT1OT0RFOk9wZW5EYXRhQXBpTTEvMTAuMC4wLjQscHJvdG9jb2xDaGFubmVsSUQ9NGI5YmVmZmUtNjk1OC00M2Q4LTg3NGYtMzA5YmE5M2IyNzMw
org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.SubscriptionException: StorageQueue: AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101 is not registered while creating subscription id=c9a279eb-6c1f-447c-84bc-c077d33a06e1
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscription.<init>(AndesSubscription.java:136)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscriptionManager.reloadSubscriptionsFromStorage(AndesSubscriptionManager.java:921)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.reloadSubscriptions(InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.java:208)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.updateState(InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.java:76)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundEventContainer.updateState(InboundEventContainer.java:268)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:70)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:40)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-11-14 07:56:50,992 [-] [DisruptorInboundEventThread-8] ERROR AndesSubscriptionManager Could not add subscription: subscriptionId=3091b9ba-867b-4539-bf25-fee511d1813d,storageQueue=AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101,protocolType=AMQP,isActive=true,subscriberConnection=Y29ubmVjdGVkSVA9LzEwLjAuMC40OjMzMTgyLzEsY29ubmVjdGVkTm9kZT1OT0RFOk9wZW5EYXRhQXBpTTEvMTAuMC4wLjQscHJvdG9jb2xDaGFubmVsSUQ9Y2Y3NDI4MDgtZGY3MS00NzJhLWFiMTEtOTY1Nzc2ZTBkNTZl
org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.SubscriptionException: StorageQueue: AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101 is not registered while creating subscription id=3091b9ba-867b-4539-bf25-fee511d1813d
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscription.<init>(AndesSubscription.java:136)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscriptionManager.reloadSubscriptionsFromStorage(AndesSubscriptionManager.java:972)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.reloadSubscriptions(InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.java:208)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.updateState(InboundDBSyncRequestEvent.java:76)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundEventContainer.updateState(InboundEventContainer.java:268)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:70)
    at org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.StateEventHandler.onEvent(StateEventHandler.java:40)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have no idea about the problem. I have looked for the error on the internet, but there are no similar cases.
Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
2018-11-14 07:56:50,989 [-] [DisruptorInboundEventThread-8] ERROR AndesSubscriptionManager Could not add subscription: subscriptionId=3091b9ba-867b-4539-bf25-fee511d1813d,storageQueue=AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101,protocolType=AMQP,isActive=true,subscriberConnection=Y29ubmVjdGVkSVA9LzEwLjAuMC40OjMzMTgyLzEsY29ubmVjdGVkTm9kZT1OT0RFOk9wZW5EYXRhQXBpTTEvMTAuMC4wLjQscHJvdG9jb2xDaGFubmVsSUQ9Y2Y3NDI4MDgtZGY3MS00NzJhLWFiMTEtOTY1Nzc2ZTBkNTZl
org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.SubscriptionException: StorageQueue: AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:OpenDataApiM1/10.0.0.101 is not registered while creating subscription id=3091b9ba-867b-4539-bf25-fee511d1813d
```

You might have probably found out the answer for this error. But the possible cause for the issue is when the `APIM` is unable to identify the correct topic connection factory related to its own node due to the sharing of the '`WSO2_MB_STORE_DB`' between the nodes.

If you refer to their [Installing and configuring databases](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM250/Installing+and+Configuring+the+Databases) documentation, it has mentioned that each Traffic Manager node must have its own Message Broker database `(WSO2_MB_STORE_DB)`.

Therefore, please check the database configurations under the `<APIM_Home>/repository/conf/master-datasource.xml` file in both nodes whether you have shared the '`WSO2_MB_STORE_DB`' between the nodes. If that is the case, you can point them to two separate fresh databases to get rid of this error.